# When using Prism, which component is responsible for configuring the container?

Tags: prism

I've seen two methods:
Method one forces the Shell to reference all the modules at compile time (which seems contrary to the purpose of the modular nature of the Prism library). In this method, the Bootstrapper configures the container using types known at compile time.

In the second method, the Bootstrapper configures the container to provide an instance of the container class (IUnityContainer or what have you). This allows the Shell project to know nothing about the modules loaded, but forces all modules to depend on a given DI framework (Since prism doesn't seem to have a generalized mechanism for configuring a container).

Which method is better, or am i missing some crucial piece of information?

Comment: To answer your title question: the bootstrapper is responsible for container configuration. What is not clear to you? There is a catalog that needs to be configured, so the container depends on the catalog configuration.

Comment: @dymanoid what's not clear to me is how a module is supposed to register services with the container if the container isn't supposed to be configured outside of the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of types registration in the container depends on the container type itself. Prism comes out with full support of two containers: MEF and Unity.

You can read about types registration in the [Development Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140(v=pandp.40).aspx):

> ### Registering Types with the Unity Container
>
> During initialization, a
>   type can register other types, such as views and services.
>   To do this,
>   the type will need to have the container injected into the module constructor. The registration can also be performed outside the code through configuration.
>
> ### Registering Types with MEF
>
> MEF uses an attribute-based system for
>   registering types with the container. As a result, adding type
>   registration to the container is simple: it requires the addition of
>   the **[Export]** attribute to a type.

So using Unity you have two options: container reference injection and configuration. For MEF, you can use attributes and container injection.

If you want to use another container implementation, such as Autofac, you have to provide an adapter to Prism.

Developing a Prism based application, you have to choose one DI container type. So there is nothing wrong in coupling all your modules with one DI framework. Of course, you could support many of them by using e.g. the `IServiceLocator` interface. But as the [Development Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec12) states:

> `IServiceLocator` is not meant to be the general-purpose container.
>   Containers have different semantics of usage, which often drives the
>   decision for why that container is chosen.
>
> In the following situations, it may
>   be appropriate for you to use the `IServiceLocator`:
>
> - You are an
>     independent software vendor (ISV) designing a third-party service that
>     needs to support multiple containers.
> - You are designing a service to
>     be used in an organization where they use multiple containers.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for, specifically
" So there is nothing wrong in coupling all your modules with one DI framework". It still feels weird, but I suppose you have to have a dependency somewhere so that everything can talk to each other.